# Are javascript object variables just reference type?

Tags: javascript, object

If you have a javascript variable that is an object and you make a new variable equal the the first variable, does it create a new instance of the object, or do they both reference the same object?

Comment: They always reference the same object.

Comment: up until you break it with `{}`

Answer (score 3):

They always reference the same object. We can see that by trying the following:

```
var x = {foo:11};
var y = x;
y.foo = 42;
console.log(x.foo);
// will print 42, not 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Both will refer to the same object.
If you want to create a new instance:

```
    var Person = function() {
      this.eyes = 2,
      this.hands = 2
    };    

    var bob = new Person();
    var sam = new Person();
```

Those two are different objects.

Here is the answer: when you create an object and then assign it to another it will refer to the same object.

Here is an example:

```
var hacker = {
  name : 'Mr',
  lastname : 'Robot'
};

console.log(hacker.name + '.' + hacker.lastname);
// Output Mr.Robot

// This variable is reference to hackers object
var anotherPerson = hacker;

console.log(anotherPerson.name + '.' + anotherPerson.lastname);
// Output Mr.Robot

// These will change hacker object name and lastname
anotherPerson.name = 'Elliot';
anotherPerson.lastname = 'Alderson';

console.log(anotherPerson.name + ' ' + anotherPerson.lastname);
// Output "Elliot Alderson"

// After it if you try to log object hacker name and lastname it would be:
console.log(hacker.name + '.' + hacker.lastname);
// Output "Elliot Alderson"
```

You can check the link here and play with it. It is not to complicated.
[JSBIN Object Hacker](http://jsbin.com/keqakahemi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: if you had an array of objects could you do var bob = new person[2](); ?

Comment: I just tried this actually and its saying it isnt a constructor

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Object Reference explained!

Look the image for better understanding. When you create an object, suppose `s1` it is having just a reference in the memory heap and now when you create another object say `s2` and say `s1 = s2` that means **both** the objects are actually pointing to the same reference. Hence when you alter either of them, both change.

[image: Object Reference Example]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like this

```
var a = { foo: "foo" };
var b = a;
```

then yes. They reference the same object.